# Next and previous always goes to page 1

Tags: asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-5

The link to Prev and Next always goes to page 1. But all the other pages with number go to the desired page: Please help. I added the @prev and @next so that I can see their values and it shows that if I'm on page 5, the previous is 4 and the next is 6. But upon clicking the Prev and Next button, I always end up at page 1.

```
<ul class="pagination btn-lg">

@{ int currentPage = (int)ViewBag.CurrentPage;}

@if (currentPage > 5)
{
    int prev = (int)ViewBag.CurrentPage - 1;
    @prev
    <li><a href=@Url.Action("Index", new { prev }) >Prev</a></li>
}

@{ int offset;        
    offset = currentPage - 4 <= 0 ? 1 : currentPage - 4;
    int maxPages = offset + 9 > ViewBag.Pages ? (int)ViewBag.Pages : offset + 9;
    }
@for (int page = offset; page <= maxPages; page++)
{        

    if (page == ViewBag.CurrentPage)
    {
        <li class="active"><a href=@Url.Action("Index", new { page }) >@page</a></li>
    }
    else
    {
        <li><a href=@Url.Action("Index", new { page })>@page</a></li>
    }
}

@if (maxPages < ViewBag.Pages)
{
    int next = currentPage + 1;
    @next 
    <li><a href=@Url.Action("Index", new { next })>Next @next</a></li>
}
```

```
public ActionResult Index(int? page)
    {
        Models.Items items = new Models.Items();
        items.loadItems(page.HasValue ? (int)page : 1);
        ViewBag.Items = items.items;
        ViewBag.Pages = (items.ItemCount / Models.Items.itemsPerPage) + 1;
        ViewBag.CurrentPage = page.HasValue ? (int)page : 1;
        return View();
    }
```

Comment: What is the signature of the `Index()` method. Assuming its `Index(int page = 1)` then you links should be `new { page = prev }` and `new { page = next }` (and you others should also be `new { page = page }`)

Comment: That did it. I did not know that I must set the parameters that way. Totally noob. Can you please post it as answer so I can mark it as such. Thanks!

Comment: I will if you edit the question to show the signature of the `Index()` method :)

Comment: I edited the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your use of

```
<a href=@Url.Action("Index", new { prev })>Prev</a>
```

is generating `href=".../Index?prev=2"` (assuming the value of `prev=2`) so you sending a value for `prev`, but not one for `page` (and your code sets its to the default value - `page = 1`)

Change the links to

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Index", new { page = prev }")>Prev</a>
```

and ditto for `new { page = next }`, and (recommended) `new { page = page }`

Side note: You can also use

```
@Html.ActionLink("Prev", "Index", new { page = prev })
```